# Error 500 shown in frontend of site. Backend working ok

Tags: joomla-3.x

Oddly, this site http://mcveighparker.com/ isn't working correctly in the frontend - showing Error 500.

The backend is working fine.

I have checked the .htaccess and this appears to be ok.

I have changed the template the site is using, but still not working correctly. Any ideas?

#### Update:

After enabling error reporting, I'm now getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'K2Model' not found in XXX/administrator/components/com_k2/models/categories.php on line 18

Comment: I'm getting a blank page. This means there's a PHP error but you have error reporting disabled. In the Global Config, set **Error Reporting** to *Development*.

Comment: Thanks @lodder - just done this and looks like a K2 error... although K2 isn't installed on that site!

Comment: K2 must be installed as the file is there. Go to **Extensions** >> **Manage** and see if you're able to uninstall it. Also, check the homepage menu item and see if the **type** is set to **K2 categories**

Comment: Check especially also the plugins. Maybe the component was removed but a plugin tries to load a class that is no longer present.